# How to write a C++ program to erase text file when number of lines is > 30

Tags: c++, file, text

This program prints something to text file. I want to erase the content of text file when number of lines exceeds 30 then again it should start to print inside text file.

```
void GPSCallback(const gps_common::GPSFix::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::ofstream output;
    output.open("file1.txt",std::ios_base::app);
    output<<"\n"<<msg->latitude<<","<<msg->longitude;
    output.close();
    usleep(10000000);
}
```

Comment: When you written 30 lines, just close and reopen?

Comment: i want it to perform automatically. more than that i am using append function so it will not work if i do as you said .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use a counter like following in function where you're calling `GPSCallback`

```
if(++count < 30)
    GPSCallback(msg);
 else{
   count =0;
   std::ofstream output;
   output.open("file1.txt");
   output.close();
   GPSCallback(msg);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    int count=0;
    output.open("file1.txt",std::ios_base::app);
    if (output.is_open()) {
    while (!output.eof()) {

      getline(name); 
      count++;
   }
   }
   if(count>=30)
   {
     // do whatever you want
   }
   output.close();
}
```

Comment: may i know where content of text file is deleted here?

Answer (score 0):

Once the 30 line limit is reached, seekp can be used reset the pointer to the beginning of the file. This will not delete the contents of the file but it will be overwritten.